# How to convert NSUrl to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

After `AVAssetExportSession` has complete export video.
I have plan to garb Video Path to upload via Youtube.
but `[GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:path defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];` 
it only accept `NSString`.
Is it possible to convert NSUrl in to NSString for video file path.

i have try to use `NSString *path = [ExportoutputURL absoluteString];`
but it crash.

Here is the Code

```
- (void)exportDidFinish:(AVAssetExportSession*)session {
    ExportoutputURL = session.outputURL;

    _exporting = NO;
    NSIndexPath *exportCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:kProjectSection];
    ExportCell *cell = (ExportCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:exportCellIndexPath];
    cell.progressView.progress = 1.0;
    [cell setProgressViewHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self updateCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:exportCellIndexPath];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:ExportoutputURL]) {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:ExportoutputURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                            if (error) {
                                                NSLog(@"writeVideoToAssestsLibrary failed: %@", error);
                                                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                                                    message:[error localizedRecoverySuggestion]
                                                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                [alertView show];
                                                [alertView release];
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                _showSavedVideoToAssestsLibrary = YES;
                                                ExportCell *cell = (ExportCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:exportCellIndexPath];
                                                [cell setDetailTextLabelHidden:NO animated:YES];
                                                [self updateCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:exportCellIndexPath];
                                                NSArray *modes = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSDefaultRunLoopMode, UITrackingRunLoopMode, nil] autorelease];
                                                [self performSelector:@selector(hideCameraRollText) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0 inModes:modes];
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }];
    }
    [library release];
}

- (void)uploadVideoFile {

    NSString *devKey = DEVELOPER_KEY;

    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
    [service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];

    NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];

    // load the file data
    NSString *path = [ExportoutputURL absoluteString];//[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_2451" ofType:@"mp4"];//[mFilePathField stringValue];
    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];

    // gather all the metadata needed for the mediaGroup
    NSString *titleStr = @"Upload Test";//[mTitleField stringValue];
    GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];

    NSString *categoryStr = @"Entertainment";//[[mCategoryPopup selectedItem] representedObject];
    GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
    [category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];

    NSString *descStr = @"GData Description";//[mDescriptionField stringValue];
    GDataMediaDescription *desc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:descStr];

    NSString *keywordsStr = @"RAGOpoR Demo";//[mKeywordsField stringValue];
    GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:keywordsStr];

    BOOL isPrivate = NO;//([mPrivateCheckbox state] == NSOnState);

    GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
    [mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
    [mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
    [mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category];
    [mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
    [mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];

    NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:path
                                               defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

    // create the upload entry with the mediaGroup and the file
    GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
    entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                    fileHandle:fileHandle
                                                      MIMEType:mimeType
                                                          slug:filename];

    SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
    [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];

    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                      forFeedURL:url
                                        delegate:self
                               didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
    [self setUploadTicket:ticket];
    GTMHTTPUploadFetcher *uploadFetcher = (GTMHTTPUploadFetcher *)[ticket objectFetcher];

}
```

Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS at

```
NSString *path = [ExportoutputURL absoluteString];
```

Comment: This should work, Maybe you released the NSURL before? Could you show some code?

Comment: what you are doing should work. please post more code.

Comment: Is your NSURL instance not nil?

Comment: Check if ExportoutputURL is nil. If it is the you probably release is somewhere before. Add `[ExportoutputURL retain];` right after you initiate it and see if it still crashes. If not then that's you problem and you should dig little deeper.

Comment: try `relativePath` instead of `absoluteString `

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, if sending the NSURL object a message is causing a crash, then it must not be `nil`. If it were `nil`, there would be no crash.

Comment: @Dimme You're assuming that that's the correct place to retain it. That is not a good assumption. It would be better to add a retain where one is needed, if one is needed; if the problem is an undue release, the correct solution is to remove it.

Comment: @xlc0212 Why `relativePath` and not `path`? The relative path may be relative to somewhere other than the current working directory, in which case it will not be accessible. The absolute path is accessible regardless of the working directory.

Comment: @PeterHosey I was suspecting it's not *really* the NSURL instance causing the problem.

Comment: @PeterHosey I'm not assuming that this is the correct place to retain. I have explicitly written `If not then that's your problem and you should dig little deeper.`, therefore urging him to look deeper and find the real problem.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> Is it possible to convert NSUrl in to NSString for video file path.

Yes. Send it an `absoluteString` message.

> i have try to use NSString *path = [ExportoutputURL absoluteString]; but it crash.

If you want a path, send the URL a `path` message. A string representing a URL is generally not a valid path; if you want a path, ask it for one.

As for the crash, it does not mean `absoluteString` is wrong. Sending `absoluteString` to an NSURL object is the correct way to get an NSString object that represents the URL. The problem is somewhere else.

> Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS at
>
> ```
> NSString *path = [ExportoutputURL absoluteString];
> ```

This probably means that `ExportoutputURL` points to something that is not `nil` but is also not a valid object. It might have pointed to an NSURL object at some point, but it doesn't now.

My guess would be that the problem is this:

> ```
> ExportoutputURL = session.outputURL;
> ```

You assign the URL to the `ExportoutputURL` instance variable, but you don't retain the object or make your own copy. Therefore, you don't own this object, which means you are not keeping it alive. It may die at any time, most probably after this method (`exportDidFinish:`) returns.

The crash is because you call `uploadVideoFile` later, after the URL object has already died. You still have a pointer to it, but that object no longer exists, so sending a message to it—*any* message—causes a crash.

There are three simple solutions:

1. Retain the URL object when you assign it to your instance variable.
2. Make your own copy of the URL object and assign that to the instance variable.
3. Declare `ExportoutputURL` as a property, with either the `strong` keyword or the `copy` keyword, and assign the object to the property, *not* the instance variable. That will call the property's setter, which, if you synthesize it or implement it correctly, will retain or copy the URL for you.

Either way, you will own the object, and that will keep it alive until you release it. Accordingly, you will need to release it when you are done with it (in `dealloc`, if not earlier), so that you don't leak it.

This all assumes that you are not using ARC. If you are using Xcode 4.2 or later, and can require iOS 4 or later, you should migrate your project to ARC, as it makes so many things much simpler. You would not need to retain or copy this object if you were using ARC, which means that migrating to ARC now is a fourth solution (but certainly a larger-scale one).

Answer (score 13):

Use either `absolutePath` or `path` as mentioned by **Miek** and **Nepster**. Expanding on their answers, the difference between lies in the prefix.

```
NSString* string1 = [url absoluteString]; // @"file:///Users/jackbrown/Music/song name.mp3"
NSString* string2 = [url path]; // @"/Users/jackbrown/Music/song name.mp3"`
```

Answer (score 11):

```
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[url path]];  ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this. I think it will help you.

In Objective c

```
NSString *testString = testUrl.absoluteString;
```

In Swift

```
var testString : String = testUrl.absoluteString
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do it like this.

```
NSString *myString = [myURL absoluteString];
```