# Converting url to string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am getting locally saved image url and now i am trying to convert it to string. I know `absoluteString` is the method to convert url to string but in this case not working.

my url is like this  (file://localhost/Users.......)

```
 NSString * imagestring = [entryObject.imageurl absoluteString];
```

but its throw error   `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc36c410` . I dont know why its happening like this

here is my object class

```
@interface EntryObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *descString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *photoImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL * imageurl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dairyId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *eventId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dateString;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *monthwiseSeparate_String;
@property (nonatomic,strong)  NSString *sortedString;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSData * entryimagedata;
```

Comment: What instance? You know that method only works on `NSURL`, nothing else?

Comment: show the class of entryObject

Comment: Maybe start with NSLog(@"%@", entryObject.imageurl);  let's see what that looks like.

Comment: without knowing what `entryObject` is, it's hard to tell. Surely it looks like `imageurl` is not returning a `NSURL`

Comment: @H2CO3 its nsurl only just name diff for you i have changed name   i have small doubt for my url i dont have http:// so i think for that reason its not working

Comment: I bet it's already a string, probably a file path.

Comment: try like this ... NSString * imagestring = [entryObject.imageurl string];

Comment: @AnoopVaidya see my object class

Comment: @ganeshmanoj That just means you **declared** it as `NSURL`, but at runtime it can be whatever. Can you show where you are initializing that object and assigning the `imageUrl` property?

Comment: @Babul i dont know how to get that method [entryObject.imageurl string]

Comment: @Babul what class should the method `string` belong to? Did you just made it up?

Comment: NSURL *url = (NSURL *)entryObject.imageurl; NSLog(@"%@", url); Just paste this and just paste your console log here pls ?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella i am saying my data in sql while saying image i am saving them locally and path in sql table while getting that path from table i am assign that path to this url and i am getting image also correctly now i want convert it string for some purpose but i am getting this problem

Comment: @Manohar entryimageurl is already url and i am getting path in nslog correctly

Comment: just paste here pls @ganeshmanoj

Comment: Are you sure that the errors is referred to that line?

Comment: Check these links.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867554/how-to-convert-nsurl-to-nsstring , http://spacetech.dk/xcode-object-c-nsurl-to-nsstring.html

Comment: @GabrielePetronella yes after i am getting that error and then crash

Comment: @Manohar i getting same nslog file://localpath/user.....

Comment: @ganeshmanoj: As you have problem somewher, you are getting url as string. But again you trying to convert it into string. Why dont you check if is url then only convert to string, and if already string use the same string.

Comment: The simply fact that you are getting the log printed means that the error is not in the `absoluteString` call. What are you doing immediately after that?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya see my object class its url and also if its string then i shouls get a method called isEqualString but i did not get this method for this

Comment: @GabrielePetronella if i remove that method everything will fine

Comment: Something is wrong in what you told us. If the `NSLog` prints just fine, then the method call cannot be the cause of the crash. What code are you using to log it?

Answer (score 2):

```
    entryObject.imageurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error that means, that you've sent a message to a object, which does not know how to interpret this message. I.e., say, you have an `NSString` object and you're sending a `absoluteString` message to it, you'll get this error.

So  the reason for that is definitely that even though `imageurl` is declared as `NSURL` you may(and probably accidentally did) assign object of some other class to it. Looks like *you just have a NSString there*, obtained from a database and to solve your problem you just don't need to transform to `NSString` as far as it's already a `NSString`. Post your code here where you set `imageURL` property, where you send `absoluteString` message. Also place a breakpoint just before the line where you send `absoluteString` to a `imageURL` and check the class of `imageURL`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSString * imagestring = (NSString *)[entryObject.imageurl absoluteString];
```

or

```
NSString * imagestring = (NSString *)[entryObject imageurl];
```